# Parse JSON file and extract only array of numbers

Tags: javascript, json

I need to parse some `JSON` files and then extract only **array of numbers**. Also, I have to accept JSON files that have only an array of numbers or one level deeper (I believed they are called direct arrays).
In addition I do not know if the JSON file includes string, boolean or other types.

My problem is recognizing the array of numbers and when I check for their type, I will get `object`.

I am not allowed to use any extra library. Is there any standard solution for this problem.

**file1.json**

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4
```

**file2.json**

```
{a:'4',b:true,c:[5,6,7]}
```

Output:

```
5,6,7
```

**file3.json**

```
{a:[1,'2',3],b:2,c:['1','2','3']}
```

Output:

```
[]
```

I need to use the result in a `Promise` so the promise will `fulfill` by the sum of numbers and `reject` if there is not an array of numbers or invalid json files.

Comment: Can you post any initial attempt that you have made? Without knowing much context on the problem, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: No there is no standard solution for this problem.  You'll need to write some code.

Comment: So you want to look for all arrays in the object that only contain numbers?

Comment: @MaxSindwani yeah. But not all. Only level 0 and level 1 array of numbers.

Comment: Why in `file3.json` the output is `[]`?

Comment: @MaxSindwani I will add my code when I get home

Comment: @TomSarduy it does not contain any array of number.It has an array of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing a shallow iteration over the object, you would simply need to check if it is an object or an array, and then check for number arrays accordingly. Given an array, you can iterate over the elements and check that each object is a number with the `typeof` operator. The function below takes in an object and outputs an array of number arrays in the object.

```js
var array1Example = [1, 2, 3];
var array2Example = [1, '2', 3, 'a'];
var object1Example = {
  a: '4',
  b: true,
  c: [5, 6, 7]
};
var object2Example = {
  a: [1, '2', 3],
  b: 2,
  c: ['1', '2', '3']
}


function isArrayOfNumbers(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] !== 'number') {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function getNumberArrays(obj) {
  var numArrays = [];
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    if (isArrayOfNumbers(obj)) {
      numArrays.push(obj);
    }
  } else if ((typeof obj === "object") && (obj !== null)) {
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) && isArrayOfNumbers(obj[key])) {
        numArrays.push(obj[key]);
      }
    }
  }

  return numArrays;
}

console.log(getNumberArrays(array1Example));
console.log(getNumberArrays(array2Example));
console.log(getNumberArrays(object1Example));
console.log(getNumberArrays(object2Example));
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses recursion to check for embedded arrays.

```
var a = ['[1,2,3,4]','{"a":"4","b":true,"c":[5,6,7]}','{"a":[1,"2",3],"b":2,"c":["1","2","3"]}','{xds}'];
var i,j,l = a.length;

function testForArray(v,depth) {
        var e,f;

        // Ensure this is not deeper than the first level
        if (depth > 1) {
                return false;
        }

        // Check if v is an array
        if (Array.isArray(v)) {
                // Use filter to find any elements which are not numeric
                // In this case, "2" is considered a string, not a number
                f = v.filter( function(e) {
                        return (isNaN(e) || typeof e === "string");
                });
                // If the filtered array is empty, all elements were numeric
                if (f.length === 0) {
                        return true;
                }
                // The filtered array was not empty
                return false;
        } else {

                // If v is an object
                if (typeof v === "object") {
                        // Loop through all the properties
                        for (e in v) {
                                // Check if each property is an array, incrementing the depth
                                if (testForArray(v[e],depth+1) === false) {
                                        // If the array is non-numeric, fail
                                        return false;
                                }
                        }
                        // Return true if it has not yet failed
                        return true;
                }
        }
        // Return null if the element tested was not an array or object
        return null;
}

// Test the function    
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(a[i]);
        try {
                j = JSON.parse(a[i]);
                console.log(testForArray(j,0));
        } catch (e) {
                console.log('caught: '+e);
        }
}
```